# Unable to parallelise workloads on the KubeCluster operator for Dask

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, dask

I want to be able to run multiple "workflows" in parallel, where each workflow submits Dask tasks and waits for it's own Dask tasks to complete. Some of these workflows will then need to use the results of it's first set of tasks to run more tasks in Dask. I want the workflows to share a single Dask cluster running in Kubernetes.

I've implemented a basic proof of concept, which works with a local cluster but fails on `KubeCluster` with the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__await__'`. This is because the operator version of `KubeCluster` doesn't seem to accept `asynchronous=True` as an argument like the old version did.

I'm fairly new to python and very new to Dask, so might be doing something very daft. I got a little further than this with the legacy `KubeCluster` approach but couldn't get `Client.upload_file()` to work asynchronously, which I'm definitely also going to need.

Very grateful for any direction in getting this to work - I'm not attached to any particular implementation strategy, as long as I can wait on a subset of Dask tasks to complete whilst others run in parallel on the same cluster, which seems like a fairly basic requirement for a distributed computing platform.

```py
import logging
import time
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
import asyncio
from dask_kubernetes.operator import KubeCluster

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-20s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger('AsyncTest')

def work(workflow, instance):
    time.sleep(5)
    logger.info('work done for workflow ' + str(workflow) + ', instance ' + str(instance))

async def workflow(id, client):
    tasks = []
    for x in range(5): tasks.append(client.submit(work, id, x))
    for task in tasks: await task
    return 'workflow 1 done'

async def all_workflows():
    cluster = KubeCluster(custom_cluster_spec='cluster-spec.yml', namespace='dask')
    cluster.adapt(minimum=5, maximum=50)
    client = Client(cluster, asynchronous=True)
    dask.config.set({"distributed.admin.tick.limit": "60s"})
    cluster.scale(15)

    logger.info('is the client async? ' + str(client.asynchronous)) # Returns false

    # work is parallelised as expected if I use this local client instead
    # client = await Client(processes=False, asynchronous=True)

    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(workflow(1, client)), asyncio.create_task(workflow(2, client)), asyncio.create_task(workflow(3, client))]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    await client.close()
    logger.info('all workflows done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(all_workflows())
```

Comment: Just a quick thought, couldn't you create a separate client object in each workflow call?
I might be totally out of scope as I'm not sure of where the error occurs.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - I spent days trying to get this to work and ended up refactoring the app to no longer need async behaviour. It’s possible whet you suggested might have worked - it’s something I didn’t try as I’d have had several clients pointed at one cluster and I’m not sure what side effects that might have had, but suffice to say I’m no longer wrestling with this problem. Cheers anyway.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have several clients pointing to one cluster, as long as individual client computations don't depend on other clients computations.